# TypeScript outFile not behaving as expected via Requirejs

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs

I am currently trying to set up and learn TypeScript and I am having trouble getting modules to behave in a sane way.

### Context

I have two ts files, `main.ts` and `types.ts`. `main.ts` is my single entry point and `types.ts` is just a test file with a couple interfaces. I also have a `tsconfig.json` file that defines, among other things, the target (ES6), module (AMD), and an outFile.

My goal is to be able to dump my whole project into a single JavaScript file instead of needing to add a whole bunch of script tags to my html.

```
// types.ts
export interface Time {
    unix: number;
}
```

```
// main.ts
import {Time} from "types";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let x: Time = { unix: 12345 };
    alert(x.unix);
});
```

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/styles.css" />
    <script data-main="static/scripts/timeapp" src="static/scripts/require.js" async></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header></header>
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

### Problem

When `tsc` compiles my project into a single file, because my `main.ts` file has an import (because of course it does), it is also being classified as a module. This is apparently causing `require.js` to... not do anything. None of my code is being executed. No errors, no output, nothing at all. Both of my files end up being wrapped in `define` blocks and I don't really know what to do.

```
define("types", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
});
define("main", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        let x = {
            unix: 12345
        };
        alert(x.unix);
    });
});
//# sourceMappingURL=time.js.map
```

I find it to be pretty unreasonable that top-level imports classify a file as a module. Exports sure, but imports alone doing that makes no sense to me. Perhaps someone can elaborate on that as well?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've finally figured it out and I am a bit livid. At no point anywhere on requirejs' website or anything I've read on SO, blogs, etc did anyone clearly explain how this works.

First off, the recommended method is utterly useless since asynchronization makes it impossible to have any guarantees about which files are loaded, and the `DOMContentLoaded` event only fires once so if one of your files loads a little late and you rely on that guarantee, your code will just never execute. So here is how you use the thing:

1. Compile your ts code into your single js file that is full of defines.
2. Create a little js file that is used as an entry point for your... entry point.
3. Load your js files synchronously in your html, despite everything you've read telling you that's the wrong way.

```
// app.js
define("types", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
});
define("app", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    let x = {
        unix: 12345
    };
    alert(x.unix);
});
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

```
// main.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    require(["app"], () => {});
});
```

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/styles.css" />
    <script src="static/scripts/require.js"></script>
    <script src="static/scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="static/scripts/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
```

If someone can provide me a better answer, I'm all ears.